# Eigenspace decomposition and nilpotent operators

Tags: linear-algebra

In the course of reading a paper involving Markov chains, I am puzzled by a     statement involving generalized eigenspaces and projections. To set the stage, let $A$ be a square matrix and denote its set of eigenvalues by $\sigma(A)$. Then we know that there exists a decomposition of the complex space $\mathbb{C}^q$ as a direct sum $\oplus_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} E_{\lambda}$ of generalized eigenspaces $E_{\lambda}$ such that $A-\lambda I$ is a nilpotent operator on $E_{\lambda}$.

The paper I'm reading notes the above but then makes the additional claim:

> In other words, there exist projections $P_{\lambda}, \lambda \in \sigma(A)$ that commute with $A$ and satisfy:
>   $$ \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} P_{\lambda} = I \quad \textrm{and} \quad A P_{\lambda} = P_{\lambda} A = \lambda P_{\lambda} + N_{\lambda}$$
>   where $N_{\lambda} = P_{\lambda} N_{\lambda} = N_{\lambda} P_{\lambda}$ is nilpotent.

The part I'm having trouble seeing is the last equality $P_{\lambda} A = \lambda P_{\lambda} + N_{\lambda}$. Is this a basic consequence of just the facts stated above or is there a non-trivial result involved here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically a definition.  That is, define $N_\lambda = P_\lambda (A - \lambda I) = P_\lambda A - \lambda P_\lambda$.  Since $P_\lambda$ is a projection, $P_\lambda N_\lambda = P_\lambda^2 (A - \lambda I) = P_\lambda (A - \lambda I) = N_\lambda$.  Since $P_\lambda$ commutes with $A$, 
$N P_\lambda = P_\lambda (A - \lambda I) P_\lambda = P_\lambda^2 (A - \lambda I) = N_\lambda$.  The nilpotence of $N$ comes from the fact that $A - \lambda I$ is nilpotent on $E_\lambda$, i.e.  $N_\lambda^k = (A - \lambda I)^k P_\lambda = 0$ for some $k$
.