# Orthogonal projections onto non-orthogonal subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a follow-up question to one I asked earlier about a closely-related claim: [Eigenspace decomposition and nilpotent operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954441/eigenspace-decomposition-and-nilpotent-operators/954505#954505)

Essentially, the setting is the same but I'm interested in an extra claim I omitted last time. Again, let $A_{q \times q}$ be a square matrix and denote its set of eigenvalues by $\sigma(A)$. Then there is a decomposition of the complex space $\mathbb{C}^q$ as a direct sum $\oplus_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} E_{\lambda}$ of generalized eigenspaces $E_{\lambda}$ such that $A-\lambda I$ is a nilpotent operator on $E_{\lambda}$. Furthermore, there exist projections $P_{\lambda}, \lambda \in \sigma(A)$ that commute with $A$ and satisfy:

> $$ \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} P_{\lambda} = I \quad \textrm{and} \quad A P_{\lambda} = P_{\lambda} A = \lambda P_{\lambda} + N_{\lambda}$$
>   where $N_{\lambda} = P_{\lambda} N_{\lambda} = N_{\lambda} P_{\lambda}$ is nilpotent, and $P_{\lambda} P_{\mu} = 0$ when $\lambda \neq \mu$.

I'm puzzled by the orthogonality claim: $P_{\lambda} P_{\mu} = 0$. Let's assume for simplicity that $A$ is diagonalizable. Then we have a set of $q$ linearly independent eigenvectors spanning the entire space. Even so, if $A$ is not symmetric then these eigenspaces are not guaranteed to be orthogonal. But this claim seems to imply that nevertheless there are projections onto these spaces which are orthogonal to each other. Is there an easy way to see why this must be true?

One person I spoke to mentioned that there is a proof of this is Nomizu's Principles of Linear Algebra, but I'm having a hard time finding it in libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $P_\lambda P_\mu=0$ is *not* an orthogonality condition. It just says that the image of one projection is in the kernel of the other projection.

The images of $P_\lambda$ and $P_\mu$ would be orthogonal (in $\mathbb C^n$) if
$$
\langle P_\lambda v, P_\mu u\rangle = u^H P_\mu^H  P_\lambda v = 0\quad\forall u,v\in\mathbb C^n.
$$ 
However, $P_\lambda P_\mu=0$ and $P_\mu^H  P_\lambda = 0$ (or $P_\mu^*  P_\lambda =0$) are not equivalent, since non-orthogonal projections are not self-adjoint.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clearing that up. But I guess a follow-up question would be: is there an easy way to see how to construct such a projection? I guess it's not so obvious...

Comment: @gogurt Not so bad once you have the minimal polynomial $f(x)$. Let $g(x)=f(x)/(x-\lambda)$. If the factor $x-\lambda$ has multiplicity one in $f$, then it and $g(x)$ are relatively prime, so there are polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ such that $a(x)g(x)+b(x)(x-\lambda)=1$. It’s not hard to show that $P=a(A)g(A)$ has the required properties.